# How to read csv and compare with a shp to create a point layer with these attributes?

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis, csv

I need to read a csv and compare with a polygon shapefile. If some cell combine with a feature attribute of the shp, This feature is added to a point layer, with a correspondent row with data of the csv and the centroid of the polygon shp. In the code below I try to do that but didn't work. How can I do this?

```
from qgis.PyQt.QtGui import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import *
import processing


source_layer = iface.addVectorLayer("/path/polygon.shp", "Setor", "ogr")
crs = source_layer.crs().toWkt()

# create a point layer
centroid_layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?field=cd_geocodi:string&crs=' + crs, 'MyPoint' , 'memory')

# read a .csv
uri = "path/teste.csv?delimiter=%s" % (",")
lyr = QgsVectorLayer(uri, 'DataBase','delimitedtext')
lyr.fields()[0].name()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(lyr)

centroid_layer.startEditing()

for feat in lyr.getFeatures():
    for source_feature in source_layer.getFeatures():
        geometry = source_feature.geometry()
        centroid = geometry.centroid()
# select the attribute
        name = source_feature.attribute("CD_GEOCODI") 
        if feat[0] == name:

# Create the new feature with the fields of the memory layer
# And set geometry and attribute before adding it to the target layer
            print feat[0], "match with", name
            centroid_feature = QgsFeature(centroid_layer.fields())
            centroid_feature.setGeometry(centroid)
            centroid_feature['cd_geocodi'] = name
            centroid_layer.addFeature(centroid_feature)
        else:
            print feat[0]

        centroid_layer.commitChanges()    

# Add the layer to the registry
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(centroid_layer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem. First, the commitChanges need to stay outside those `for` loops. Second, the logic is correct, but the length of data wich I used to compare was wrong.